# What does class `type.__init__` and `type.__new__` do when creating a new `type` instance(i.e. class)?

Tags: python

As is known to all, there are many jobs are done behind the scenes when creating a new `class` in Python, such as setting attributes like `__dict__`, `__class__`, `__metaclass__`, etc.

I know that when creating a new class, the `type.__new__` method will be called, and `type.__init__` will also be called on condition that `call.__new__` returns a instance of `type`. So I guess these two methods might be in charge of some of the work, but I cannot find any description in docs about their real function. My question is, what exactly do these two methods do for making a `class`?

***EDIT:***

I know what a metaclass is and what roughly metaclass does in the process of creating a `type` instance, but I am wondering about how these two methods cooperate to achieve the job of creating a `type` instance. Maybe @BrenBarn is right that this is implementation related. And I just want to make sure about that. For example, if I rewrite the `__new__` method in my own metaclass `T`, and return `type(clsname, bases, dct)` directly instead of calling `__new__` in base class `type` as what people usually do, then neither `T.__init__` nor `type.__init__` will be called, since returned object is not an instance of `T`. If so, what am I expecting to miss owing to the absense of  `__init__`? And also, can I expect that to be a consistent behavior across various implementations?

Comment: Is your question what do they do, or what is the result?  I don't think the actual operations of those methods are explicitly defined in the docs; only the existence of various attributes like `__class__` is defined.  (You can look in the C source code to see what they do on a lower level, but that may vary from one implementation of Python to another.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It is far from clear that this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @BrenBarn: it is either too broad or a duplicate of a good metaclass reference answer. I picked the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have edited my question and trying to clarify it. And @MartijnPieters, maybe I am asking too abroad as you suspect, but I do not think it is a duplicate of "What is a metaclass in Python?".

Comment: `type.__new__` does a lot of things and is about 700 lines long, without counting all the helper functions. You might as well just [read it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L2319). `type.__init__` does [basically nothing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L2244).

Comment: If you're just wondering about how the division of work goes, that's pretty simple: all the work is in `type.__new__`. (In general, a well-written class should either have all the initialization in `__new__` or all the initialization in `__init__`, throughout its entire inheritance hierarchy.)

Comment: Apparently, `type.__init__` does something, because when I removed my `__init__` method from a class based on type, `type.__init__` raised an error saying that it requires one or three arguments. All my `__init__` method does is return. My `__new__` method does all the work, including calling `type.__new__` when not returning an already-existing class.

Answer (score 2):

> am wondering about how these two methods cooperate to achieve the job of creating a type instance

The `type.__init__` method is only responsible for checking that there are 1 or 3 arguments and that there are no keyword arguments.   The C source code for this is in the `type_init()` function in `Objects/typeobject.c`.

The `type.__new__` method does all of the rest work in creating a new class. Here are the steps for `type_new_impl` in `Objects/typeobject.c`:

- type_new_init()
- type_new_set_attrs()
- PyType_Ready()
- fixup_slot_dispatchers()
- type_new_set_names()
- type_new_init_subclass()